How to Pin Dedicated CPUs to Pods in OpenShift Without Interference from Other Processes?
I'm working with customers who require the configuration of dedicated CPUs in OpenShift. While I’m familiar with options like CPU isolation and reserved CPU cores, I’m looking for a way to pin specific CPU cores to a pod. The goal is to ensure that these CPU cores are fully dedicated to the pod and not accessible to other pods or processes running on the operating system. I'm also familiar with taskset/cset and other linux commands, but need this to be addressed on the OpenShift/K8s level.
Is there a way to achieve this in OpenShift, ensuring that the CPU core remains exclusive to the assigned pod without any interference from other processes?
UPDATE: I’m looking for exclusive cpu usage. Without the option for system services of the node or other non pinned pods catching the entire vcpus of the machine. For example, if I’m asking for 4 CPU’s. Let’s assume I get 2,3,4,5 out of a 24 core node. I would like to avoid pods or aervices without pinning to get all cpus (0-23) which will also get 2,3,4,5.

Yes, OpenShift’s CPU Manager feature can take care of this. I won’t reproduce all the instructions here, see the previous link for details; the gist of it is that you need to enable the CPU Manager in a KubeletConfig, set its policy to static, specify a label to use on nodes where you want dedicated CPUs, and label those nodes.
Once the CPU manager is running, pods scheduled on managed nodes with an integer value for CPU requests and limits will get dedicated CPUs:
[…]
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 1
      limits:
        cpu: 1
[…]

in a Pod spec would dedicate a single CPU to that pod.

Thank you for you answer. We already do the performance profile. But that doesn’t guarantee me that the processes of the node won’t catch these cpus allocated to the int-based-pod on the machine. Nor does it guarantee other non integer workload won’t take these CPUs. Am I right? I’ll update the question
